# imap_fetchbody - Encoded body error

Tags: php, android, imap

I am trying to fetch a particular section of an email body using:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody ($imap_stream,$n,1);
```

This works fine for emails sent using Outlook, Hotmail, Yahoo etc. But when I try and fetch the body of the an email sent from a Blackberry or Andriod device, the message is encoded and scrambled such as:

```
xmb250IHN0eWxlPSdjb2xvcjojRjk3MWIxMDNiMTEyYjExOGI0N2I1MWI1
```

Although the body is encoded, the header is fine. **How do I decode the message body of en email sent from an Android or Blackberry device?**

Thank you,

Chris.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to run [imap_fetchstructure](http://us.php.net/imap_fetchstructure) to get the encoded value.  If that value equals 3 you need to decode via [imap_base64](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-base64.php).

I've used the following before (Can't remember if it was ever tested with sent mobile email before though):

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($stream, $msgno);
$text = imap_fetchbody($stream, $msgno, $partnum);   
if($structure->encoding == 3) {
    $text = imap_base64($text);
} else if($structure->encoding == 4) {
    $text = imap_qprint($text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working on some of the emails. Some of the emails encode values are O but are still encoded. I am looking into the imap_fetchstructure array in detail at present. Will get back to you.

Comment: Sorted. I just had to catch a different location of the encoded value in the array for a different email client using: `if($structure->parts[0]->encoding == 3 ||$structure->encoding == 3 ) `. All working now. Thank you. Upvoted.

Comment: Careful. $structure->parts can not be exist. Use : if (($obj_structure->encoding == 3) || isset($obj_structure->parts) && ($obj_structure->parts[0]->encoding == 3)) {